# Degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ where $\omega^{3}=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I am working through Rotman's *Galois Theory*, and I came across an example that confused me a bit. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

I am not sure, why the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ is only 2. $\omega$ if I am not mistaken is a cube root of unity, and I assumed that adjoining it would give an extension of degree 3.

When viewed as a vector space of $\mathbb{Q}$ does $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ not have {$1,\omega,\omega^{2}$} as a basis?

It is clear to me however, that $\omega$ is indeed a root of $x^{2}+x+1$, for $\omega^{2}+\omega+1 = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}+1=0 $

In light of this, is the reason that {$1,\omega,\omega^{2}$} is not a basis because $\omega^{2} = -\omega-1$? The basis I proposed was not linearly independent?

Finally, is there a general way of determining the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\omega^{n}=1$?

Comment: The minimal polynomial for a primitive $n$th root of unity (known as the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial) has degree $\phi(n)=|\{1\leq k\leq n:\text{gcd}(k,n)=1\}|$ (the Euler totient function).

Comment: Ah, so the extension is degree $2$ because $\phi(3)=2$?

Comment: And yes, $\{1,\omega\}$ spans $\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q$, which is in line with the extension being of degree $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The *minimal* polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbf Q$, $x^2+x+1$, has degree $2$, hence $\,[\mathbf Q(\omega):\mathbf Q]=2$. A basis is $(1,\omega)$. Indeed: 
\begin{align*}
\omega^2 &= -\omega-1\\
\omega^3&= -\omega^2-\omega=-2\omega-1\\
\text{&c.}
\end{align*}