# Degree of the field of rational numbers extended by a complex number

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

So I want to calculate the degree of the following fields over the field of the rational numbers:
$$\mathbb{Q} \left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right),$$

$$\mathbb {Q} \left(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{1+i}\right)$$

I know that if I extend the rational field by irrational numbers I can use the degrees of the minimal polynomials and the multiplication formula for field extensions. 
But with the complex numbers I don't know how to figure out the degree of the minimal polynomials.

Comment: First extension has been answered in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277734/degree-of-mathbbq-omega-mathbbq-where-omega3-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember that $e^{2\pi i}=1$, now start with $\alpha =e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and see if you can get a polynomial in $\alpha$ with rational coefficients.

Let me help you with $\alpha=\sqrt{1+i}$. $$\alpha =\sqrt{1+i}\\\alpha^2=1+i\\\alpha^2-1=i\\(\alpha^2-1)^2=-1\\\alpha^4-2\alpha^2+2=0$$ So the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt{1+i}$ is $x^4-2x^2+2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks! So I have degree 2 for the first one. And degree 4 for the second, because the minimal polynomials of $\sqrt{1+i}$ has degree 4 and $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{-i} * (1+i)$.